# Hurricane season in Mexico

Tags: weather-and-climate, mexico

September is in the hurricane season. But are there parts of Mexico that are pretty much hurricane free and have sunny weather (I want to spend the days on the beach) during that month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the Pacific side is OK, it's just the Atlantic side that gets hit hard (again, usually).  [Puerto Vallarta](http://visitpuertovallarta.com/) is a popular spot on the Pacific side.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How's it with the rain on the Pacific side? I read that it on average rains 14 days in September but that number might not be that bad for the Pacific side? I was thinking of Ixtapa. Thanks.

Comment: http://visitpuertovallarta.com/about-puerto-vallarta/weather/  Sounds like evening/night showers in Sept

Comment: Rain in Puerto Vallarta is pretty much a daily occurrence during the rainy season (roughly Jul-Oct), but it usually rains for 30-60 minutes in the afternoon, then clears up again.  It won't generally interfere with your vacationing plans, except to encourage you to spend an hour sipping coffee or shopping rather than swimming.

Comment: Usually, but not always. My old favourite beach on the Mexican Pacific and its neighbour beaches were destroyed twice in one year by hurricanes: Hurricane Pauline in October 1997, then Hurricane Rick in November 1997.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently in Mexico, on the Pacific side, during hurricane season.

If you want sun it's hard to beat Baja Sur (southern Baja). There is little rain unless a cyclone comes through, and the sun and heat are punishing to say the least.

The weather on the mainland in the peak of summer (August/September) is hot, muggy, wet, and bug ridden. Baja is also pretty bad but minus a lot of the moisture.

I honestly don't know anyone who's spent August and September in Mexico that would voluntarily do it again. The weather is pretty bad, you'll hide in an AC'd room as much as you can, and cyclones can affect you anywhere.